# Razor like syntax in ASPX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been reading a lot about this razor thing, and some examples present something like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="@Model.Title" />
```

I would like to do the same on my ASPX view. But no matter what I try, it just won't work. In other words, writing the following :

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<%: Model.Title %>" />
```

Gave me a view with 2 text box, instead of what i'm trying to do. I don't want to use the HTML Helpers as they wont solve my problem. (which is to return a value from the view that is not included on my model).

Comment: Are you using MVC or are you trying to use an alternate view engine in webforms? If you are using MVC what version are you using (1-3)?

Comment: I'm using MVC 3 with the ASPX view engine.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is in your view and not in your model then do not reference the model. Just reference the variable name you assigned to the value in your view.

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="@VariableName" />
```

Comment: This is true for razor, but i'm using the ASPX view engine.